# Azure AD Domain Services Single-sign-on with Application Proxy using KCD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have connected an Azure VM with Azure AD Domain Services. I am trying to set up sso for IIS web app which authenticates users using Integrated Windows.

I have followed the guide to setup the Application Proxy and I am stuck at Delegating KCD. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-proxy-sso-using-kcd/

Has anyone tried to authenticate users with Integrated Windows Authentication via Azure AD SSO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as in Azure AD Domain Services you don't have access to the domain controller so you can't configure KCD for the connector.

Disclaimer - I worked in the App Proxy team :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vainolo. Is there any other way for me to set up my IWA IIS app to use SSO with Azure AD Domain Services?

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry.